# Preferred way of linking models

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a preferred way of linking models in Monaco (ctrl + click)? I'm implementing a code editor with external tabs management + file tree, one editor, multiple models being swapped between. It would be ideal for users to be able to ctrl + click includes (references to other models, e.g: `@include 'abc'`) and make them "followable".

What I'm currently doing is registering codelenses to open said models. In the lenses definition I do a `model.findMatches(regexp)`, match the `include` statement, get the include filename from the match groups and register the open command. This is currently working, but I don't know if there's a better, more standard, less intensive way of having this functionality (preferably via ctrl + click) than scanning the model viewport for matches everytime the lenses are generated (`keyup`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here after four months. Yes, you don't want lenses to register links but rather register them through your language `registerLinkProvider` so users can `CTRL + click` them as usual.

To do so use the `monaco.languages.registerLinkProvider` method which returns an object with two methods `provideLinks` and `resolveLink`.

`provideLinks` is where you'll want to do your parsing and capture your links, whatever you return in this method it will get passed to `resolveLink`.

`resolveLink` will take whatever you returned from `provideLinks` so you can handle your linking logic.

Hope this helps others and remember, [this is your best Monaco friend](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html).